# Send and process an unknown number of parameters to an ASP.NET WebMethod with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I am building a poll application.. The user enters a question, then clicks on a button to dynamically create textboxes for the answers..

I then use the following code to serialize the form:

```
var formData = $("#form1").find("input,textarea,select,hidden").not("#__VIEWSTATE,#__EVENTVALIDATION").serializeObject();
```

I use jQuery.ajax to send the serialized information to a WebMethod using `data: formData`

This is where my problem starts.. If it was a static form, my webmethod would be;

```
<WebMethod()>_
Public Shared Function addPoll(byval question as string, byval answer1 as string, etc...)
```

Since they are dynamic, how do I define my parameter(s) and how can I loop through them in the webmethod function?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you use a `Dictionary` object?  They're pretty easy to serialize/ deserialize.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Never used it before..

Comment: I gave an example down below.  Hopefully that will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Per request, an example of using a generic list to pass around data as an argument (and please forgive me if my VB.NET syntax is not up to snuff, I've been concentrating on C# for years now)

First, you'd define an object:

```
Public Class QA
    Public Property Question() As String
        Get
            Return m_Question
        End Get
        Set
            m_Question = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Question As String
    Public Property Answer() As String
        Get
            Return m_Answer
        End Get
        Set
            m_Answer = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Answer As String
End Class
```

Then define your webmethod:

```
<WebMethod> _
Protected Sub addPoll(args As IEnumerable(Of QA))
    For Each qaPair As QA In args
        'do stuff with qaPair
    Next
End Sub
```

jQuery would need pass this object to the backend as a JSON string representing an array of objects like so:

```
[
    { Question: "what is the answer to life, the universe, and everything?",
        Answer: "42" },
    { Question: "what is the average velocity of a laden swallow?",
        Answer: "African or European?" }
]
```

which can be parsed using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y300) into a List of QA objects.

Hopefully that clears it up for you?